# Can Dimensional Barrier be used on Link monsters?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

[Dimensional Barrier](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Dimensional_Barrier):

> Call one monster type (Ritual, Xyz, Synchro, Pendulum, Fusion) For the rest of this turn neither player can summon that kind of monster. And any monster of that type already on the field have their effects negated.

With the new link format of Yu-Gi-Oh, can this handy trap be used to stop the summoning of link monsters?

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot use Dimensional Barrier on link monsters as this is the current text.

> Call one monster type (Ritual, Xyz, Synchro, Pendulum, Fusion) For the
>   rest of this turn neither player can summon that kind of monster. And
>   any monster of that type already on the field have their effects
>   negated.

Because it explicitly mentions monster card types, only the mentioned ones can be used. If the card didn’t explicitly mention certain types then you could have used it on link monsters (so taking out the part in brackets). So currently you cannot use dimensional Barrier on link monsters, unless Konami give the card an errata (rewording the card text).

Please see [this reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/yugioh/comments/6l2ivt/will_d_barrier_get_erratad/) for more information.

Comment: It better be reprinted. Link summons haven't fixed a thing, they have only made the game even more broken than it already is.

Comment: It probably won’t be reprinted. The card is too powerful already, reprinting it to stop link summons would make it even more powerful. It’s highly unlikely

Comment: Seeing as  how it comes in Structure Deck: Cyberse Link, I doubt it will be errata'd

Comment: @JonMilliken it was even reprinted in the mega tins which came out a couple months ago, if it was going to be errata’d it would’ve been done by now

Comment: It just shuts down every other monster type even more than the link rules already do.

Comment: The thing is, depending on how you run your deck, you can still get around the new rules on Links. people are just so focused on how it limits everything that they can't be creative on how to work around it.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes you can.**

The key point is:

> Call one monster type...

Maybe the card wording has not been updated to include Link monsters as some of the options, but surely they will soon (imagine all other cards that have to be updated in such way)

However as Link monsters **are indeed** a valid Monster Type you can go ahead and use it on them.

Comment: This is wrong. Yes link monsters are a monster type but they are not listed in the list explicitly mentioned on the card.

Comment: Well don't they plan to change that? Because Link monsters are pretty lethal now adays

Comment: @Therationalduelist yes they will surely will. I don't agree with Whats the point, taking too literally what the card says IMO. Usually, when Konami wants to exclude something from an effect, most of the times they specify it something like *Target one monster type, except ...*. And yes, they will surely errata many cards to come to include that if they consider it necessary.

Comment: I agree. I mean my Dragons are one of my most powerful decks, but when I go against Spyrals or something, I have a hard time making a move  because they can link summon so much stuff and it's not even fair. There need to be more traps and such that keep such monsters in check like Break Off Trap Hole. And personally I really am sick of all these decks because they are so overpowered. However I have found one extremely fatal flaw: They rely too much on their extra deck. If it was locked by Amorphage Goliath, or so, they would be so weak. That's why they need more cards to lock the extra deck.

Comment: @DarkCygnus it's a game where you have to take the literal cards effect, you can't just choose the way it works to suit yourself. From the reddit link i posted "Dimensional Barrier is PSCT, that means it uses clear and consistent wording. Those types in brackets aren't examples, those are the things you can choose. "

Comment: @Therationalduelist You are saying the following : You should buy a lottery ticket because they will probably pick your number. Thats not how something works... Your numbers have to be correct just like the summary on the card has to match the monster type.

Comment: @WhatsThePoint wouldnt trust reddit on the official happenings on ygo. I am positive it will be reworded, but it is also a bit likely it wont so Links have their moment of glory before bringing them down... but it doesn't make sense to exclude just one monster type. Seems like time will be useful here to se how this evolves

Comment: The card also specifically EXCLUDES "normal", and "effect"

Comment: If this were the case, then cards that specify, e.g., Fusion/Synchro/Xyz but no other types would be allowed to also be used on Ritual, Pendulum, and Link monsters... which they aren't.